# SQL: Taking the result of of query and using it another - combine

Tags: sql, database

I have two SQL queries, one that uses the other after getting its result.

`SELECT users.data from users WHERE users.data2 = value`

`SELECT mods.data FROM mods WHERE mods.data2 = (result of previous query)`

How would I combine these statements? There are similar questions as such, but I'm new to SQL and don't understand them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to join them is with the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT mods.data FROM mods WHERE mods.data2 IN 
    (SELECT users.data from users WHERE users.data2 = value)
```

but there are plenty of others...

For example you could join them:

```
SELECT mods.data 
FROM mods 
JOIN users ON mods.data2 = users.data
WHERE users.data2 = value
```

These may produce different outputs though depending on how your data is structured.

Comment: Reading around, using IN seems to be advised again.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT m.data 
FROM mods m
INNER JOIN users u ON m.data2 = u.data
WHERE u.data2 = value
```

Comment: typo: should be ...ON  m.data2 = u.data2

Comment: @ Vikram : I don't think so. Unless I misunderstood the question - results of the first OP's query is `users.data` (`SELECT users.data ... `), not users.data2

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact RDBMS, you could use [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (CTEs), available in more recent MS SQL versions.