# Combine SQL query result with another query statement under one query? (Complicated)

Tags: sql, derby

I currently want to combine two SQL queries into one. This is a bit similar to [SQL: Taking the result of of query and using it another - combine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888140/sql-taking-the-result-of-of-query-and-using-it-another-combine). Suppose there are two queries:

> **SQL Statement**

```sql
1.) SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT B.example1  
          FROM EXAMPLE1A A  
          INNER JOIN EXAMPLE1B B ON A.ID = B.ID  
          WHERE A.ABC ='ABC' 
          ORDER BY A.ORDER_BY ) as colstate

2.) SELECT colstate 
    FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE 
    WHERE EFG LIKE '%' 
      AND BGTHAN >= '1' 
      AND SMTHAN <= '100' 
    ORDER BY ORDER_BY ASC
```

I want to use the result in query 1.) as the colstate (column statement) in query 2.). But:

> **What Have I tried is:**

```sql
SELECT (SELECT B.example1  
        FROM EXAMPLE1A A  
        INNER JOIN EXAMPLE1B B 
           ON A.ID = B.ID  
        WHERE A.ABC ='ABC' 
        ORDER BY A.ORDER_BY ) 
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE 
WHERE EFG LIKE '%' 
  AND BGTHAN >= '1' 
  AND SMTHAN <= '100' 
ORDER BY ORDER_BY ASC
```

And it turns out to be **Error: Scalar subquery is only allowed to return a single row**, how should I replace the "=" into "IN"? Or is my statement totally wrong?

Comment: What is relation between 2 queries ? i.e. why you need 2nd query if you get result from 1st query ?

Comment: By selecting this: SELECT (SELECT...) you should obtain a single value, not a rowset. You can take topmost or bottom or average or any other aggregate result over the inner select, but not all rows.

Comment: because they are from different tables?
The result of the first sql query is the table_column_name in the  2nd. Like `SELECT [table_column_name]...`

Comment: Nope. Generally SELECT is "give me this, this and this column value from each row". Instead of the first "this" you put something that returns more than 1 value (the inner query). You cannot associate a single value to a set of values, each row can contain only 1 value per field

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: ok, thanks...@jim
Apache Derby Client, JDBC-ODBC Bridge? @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Combine two queries into one" - that's not a good specs. Try to find out what exactly you want to get as a FLAT 2-dimensional table, think of nested SELECTs as of nested loops where the inner one can only set a single value for parent's row. Like this:

```
[Outer loop - parent row]
    [Inner loop - children rows]
        // all you can do here is change a single parent's field to anything
        // like constant/sum/avg/topmost/ugly-subquery-returning-a-single-result
    [/Inner loop]
[/Outer loop]
```

Comment: is there possible to run the [outer loop-parent] first and then pass the result to the [Inner loop - children] within one execute?

Comment: From inside of the inner loop you can only know what is the current parent's row - so you can use its values in subquery like: select t1.field1, (select top 1 t2.field1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id) from table1 t1. Maybe you need to swap inner and outer?

Comment: ARe there "colstate" fields in  EXAMPLEA and EXAMPLEB tables?

Comment: I just go through your idea + union, check whether it will be a magic or not...XD
nope, the colstate just a random name for keeping the results for the first query...

Answer (score 0):

The error says that query you are using as column statement must return at most a single row.

It should probably look something like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT B.example1  
        FROM EXAMPLE1A A  
        INNER JOIN EXAMPLE1B B 
           ON A.ID = B.ID  
        WHERE A.ABC ='ABC' 
          AND A.SOME_COLUMN = E.SOMECOLUMN // retrieve only relevant data for this row
        ORDER BY A.ORDER_BY ) 
FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE E 
WHERE EFG LIKE '%' 
  AND BGTHAN >= '1' 
  AND SMTHAN <= '100' 
ORDER BY ORDER_BY ASC
```